# Passing variable from apex class to vf page in lightning aura enabled class method

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, getter, variable

Can we pass a getter value from apex to VF page in lightning aura enabled classes?
I have a class which has a variable defined

```
public static Integer testvariable{get;set;}
```

now I have an auraenabled method which populates the value for this variable depending on certain condition
but when I am trying to use this in my VF page it is showing as null

I tried the following ways to pass the values

1)By simply declaring the variable with get;set and in VF page
{!testvariable}

2)By using a getter method

```
public Integer getChecktestvariable(){
        
        System.debug('when in Checktestvariable'+testvariable);
        return testvariable ;}
```

The debug log shows the method was not called at all
please help

Comment: What is the reason to use AuraEnabled in VF? AuraEnabled is for LWC and Aura

Comment: one more time, where do you initialize testVariable?

Comment: the testVariable is just delcared as shown and populated inside an AuraEnbled method

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should [edit] your question to include what you're actually trying to do, so we can help you better. This proposed solution presumably won't work, but without knowing what you're actually trying to do, it's hard to offer better advice.